# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android

I need to select the data from **MySql** to **Spinner** in Android.

I don't know where the error and how can I solved this.

```js
public void selectfromclass(){

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

    String test= cyclespiner.getText().toString();
    Log.d("toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooop",test);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", test));



    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxx/getclassprof.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       //     sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }




    try {

        JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray JA = json.getJSONArray("matier");
       /// JSONObject json = null;
        roll_no = new String[JA.length()];
        name = new String[JA.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
            json = JA.getJSONObject(i);

            name[i] = json.getString("class");
        }


        spinner_fn();

    } catch (Exception e) {
```

and this is the code php

```html
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$name=$_POST['name'];
 $response["matier"] = array();

$r=mysql_query("SELECT class FROM classadmin WHERE cycle= '".$name."'",$con);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{


   $product["class"] = $row["class"];
       array_push($response["matier"], $product);

//echo $fin."<br>";
}
print(json_encode($response));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and this is the result of json

```html
{"matier":[{"class":"azerty"}]}
```

Comment: what is the error???

Comment: the error is 
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: i think the error is json output but im not sure

Comment: Error is in parsing code where you are trying to parse the json string. Please post the log to get the correct problem and help you in better way.

Comment: the log 

 8487-8487/androidhive.info.materialdesign E/Fail 2﹕ java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
05-21 08:23:35.387    8487-8487/androidhive.info.materialdesign E/Fail 3﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"matier":[]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies here

```
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     //     sb.append(line + "\n");
  }
```

commenting the `sb.append`, you are not filling up the `StringBuilder` with the data you get from the network, leaving it empty. An empty string is not a valid JSON, and this is  causing your exception. Since you are still using the Apache HttpClient, the easiest way to convert the `Entity` to String is to use,

```
 EntityUtils.toString(entity)
```

Edit:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxx/getclassprof.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

// here goes the code to parse result
```

Comment: not work or I dnt understand how can used in my code

Comment: this is the error after edit 

 8487-8487/androidhive.info.materialdesign E/Fail 2﹕ java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
05-21 08:23:35.387    8487-8487/androidhive.info.materialdesign E/Fail 3﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"matier":[]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: it's correct.  result is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray

Comment: but I need to sotre the reslut in Jsoon array to display in spiner

Comment: you have to learn to parse the json, and the differences between JSONObject and  JSONArray. It is a common task when you do work  on a client